# div id doesn't work as class

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

So I've been having this problem for days. I've googled half of the internet. Changed my code a zilion times. Already had to back it up so many times. But I can't seem to make it work or understand.

I changed one of my css ids to class, because I need to use it more then once in one page. And it stopped working. It only works when it's a ID. From my search I think it has something to do with specifity, but I've tried alot of things and it still only works as id.

The problem is with .carousel_dots

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b2y8E/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="panel" title="Desiree Charms" id="desiree_charms" style="overflow: hidden;"
    data-appbuilder-object="page">
        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="carousel_page">
                <h2>Desiree Charms</h2>
                <p><img src="images/desiree_charms.jpg" style="width: 85%; height: 85%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto "
                data-appbuilder-object="image" class="" title="">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel_page">
                <h2>Page Two</h2>
                <p>Text and images for Page Two goes here. Swipe to go to the
                    next page.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="carousel_dots"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel {
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:0 -10px;
    }

.carousel_page {
        overflow: auto; 
        -webkit-scrolling:touch;
        padding:0 10px;
    }

.carousel_dots {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto; 
        margin-right: auto; 
        clear: both;
        position:relative;
        top:0;
        z-index:200;
    }

.carousel_paging {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #ccc;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        display:inline-block;
    }

.carousel_paging_selected {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: #000;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        display:inline-block;
    }

.carousel h2 {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

It's a carousel for a mobile app. This one https://github.com/krisrak/appframework-templates/blob/master/template-CarouselViewApp.html

So I think the problem is in this piece of code in the jquery

```
// Create the paging dots
            if (this.pagingDiv) {
                this.pagingDiv.innerHTML = ""
                for (i = 0; i < this.childrenCount; i++) {

                    var pagingEl = document.createElement("div");
                    pagingEl.id = this.container.id + "_" + i;
                    pagingEl.pageId = i;
                    if (i !== this.carouselIndex) {
                        pagingEl.className = this.pagingCssName;
                    }
                    else {
                        pagingEl.className = this.pagingCssNameSelected;
                    }
                    pagingEl.onclick = function() {
                        that.onMoveIndex(this.pageId);
                    };
                    var spacerEl = document.createElement("div");

                    spacerEl.style.width = "20px";
                    if(this.horizontal){
                        spacerEl.style.display = "inline-block";
                        spacerEl.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
                    }
                    else{
                       spacerEl.innerHTML="&nbsp;";
                       spacerEl.style.display="block";
                    }

                    this.pagingDiv.appendChild(pagingEl);
                    if (i + 1 < (this.childrenCount))
                        this.pagingDiv.appendChild(spacerEl);
                    pagingEl = null;
                    spacerEl = null;
                }
                if(this.horizontal){
                    this.pagingDiv.style.width = (this.childrenCount) * 50 + "px";
                    this.pagingDiv.style.height = "25px";
                }
                else {
                    this.pagingDiv.style.height = (this.childrenCount) * 50 + "px";
                    this.pagingDiv.style.width = "25px";
                }
            }
            this.onMoveIndex(this.carouselIndex);

        }

    };
    return carousel;
})();
```

somehow it worked with id but not with a class

Comment: Are you overwriting an existing style or is it something to do with javascript? If it's to do with style, you could do something like `.panel .carousel_dots { /* your style here */ }` which is more specific than just `.carousel_dots`.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue; your current code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/zC8rP/.

Comment: I'm also using jquery. This is because I'm using a carousel for a mobile app. The carousel is working, but the dots wish specify the amount of pages and the selected page. isn't working. only the sliding is

Comment: `It still only works as id`. I don't see anything in your `.carousel_dots` div, so could you please provide JS code (or better, a fiddle) ?

Comment: Can you show us the css for `#desiree_charms`

Comment: The css has (next to) nothing to do with the functionality of the slider. If your jQuery target an element with `id` and you change that to a class, the script will stop working. Could you add more of your code?

Comment: Ok I think I'm starting to understand. The problem is with jquery, I thought it was with the CSS because when I changed the .carousel_dots to #carousel_dots it worked.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b2y8E/1/

Comment: So what are the changes I've to make for the jquery to work with the class instead of the Id? I tried changing Id to classname in jquery but it didn't work. I don't know jquery yet, I've started to code recently and jquery still confuses me.

Comment: Does it work if you keep the class but give it an id of something else? - eg `<div id="test" class="carousel_dots"></div>` and then change that id to something else for the second one?

Comment: @user3701780 try adding `!important` at the end of every value ( for example `margin-left: auto!important;`  ), and let me know if that works. Then I know what your problem is.. but it is important that you don't leave the `!important` statements there.. (no pun intended)

Comment: it didn't work with !important either